# Navigation with up button guidelines

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I am little confused when dealing with Google Drive app.

For me drilling down the directory tree is drilling down in the hierarchy of the app. So why when I hit up button I get to the home screen. I would expect to get to the parent folder.

For me Google Drive app breaks the up navigation model with this behaviour. This is apparent when you go through search to the folder that is located down the directory tree and hitting up button sends you home and back button sends you back to search. What I would like to see there is to go up the directory tree.

I am working on an app where I also deal with file system and would like to know what would be the expected behaviour for this.

Comment: have you read the docs on the navigation stuff? because it sounds like it matches what the docs say: the "up" button should take you to the parent activity, the back button should take you to the previous screen

Comment: This is from the guidelines:"The Up button is used to navigate within an app based on the hierarchical relationships between screens. For instance, if screen A displays a list of items, and selecting an item leads to screen B (which presents that item in more detail), then screen B should offer an Up button that returns to screen A."

Comment: so the home screen would be the hierarchical parent of the directory tree.

Comment: My home screen is directory screen.

Comment: i meant for google drive. in your case, there wouldn't be an up button from the directory

Comment: I understand what you mean. So lets assume that GDrive is OK. At least for me it is not enough. My user can from notification get inside deeper in the directory tree and from there I would like to allow him to navigate higher. Back will get him back to home screen. This also applies for search.

Comment: there is a way to define a "parent" activity in the AndroidManifest. that would handle the "up" case. if you want to do something special when the user presses the back button, you will need to override `onBackPressed()` anywhere you need special behavior

Answer (score 0):

You are right about Google Drive not using the Up navigation button properly before.

However, in the latest Google Drive, this problem is eliminated all together as Google Drive is now using a Navigation Drawer.

In this case, there is no Up Navigation button as clicking on the Google Drive app Icon causes the nav drawer to slide open. But pressing the Back Key takes you up the folder structure according to the order of traversal!